# RegEx / Regular expression for european dates ("j. F Y")

Tags: regex, string, swift, date, swift2

I need a way to find dates using `.RegularExpressionSearch` in `Swift 2.0`, written in an european-style like 
**"6. November 2015"**, **"13. Februar 2015"** or **"24.Dezember2015"** (with an optional space).

I tried a lot expressions using [this very helpful regex tester Web site](http://www.regexr.com), however, I couldn't get a working solution. I appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm using Swift 2.0 / .RegularExpressionSearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d+\\.\\s*\\p{L}+\\s*\\d{4}", options: [])
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI4oD5/3)

The regex will match:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits (you can limit with a limiting quantifier to 1 or 2: `\d{1,2}`)
- `\.` - literal dot
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `\p{L}+` - a sequence of letter-only symbols
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `\d{4}` - exactly 4 digits.

[Swift code demo](http://swiftstub.com/779423092):

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String, text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
            options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

let string = "6. November 2015 and 13. Februar 2015 or 24.Dezember2015 1. My christmas gift 2015 01.01.2015"
let matches = matchesForRegexInText("\\d+\\.\\s*\\p{L}+\\s*\\d{4}", text: string)
print(matches)
```

Results: `["6. November 2015", "13. Februar 2015", "24.Dezember2015"]`

Comment: I guess it does not matter here, you may use [`matchesForRegexInText(regex: String, text: String)`](http://swiftstub.com/312582395), too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works, but recognizes also **"01.01.2015"**. And even with the help of your explanation, I couldn't figure out how to disallow digits. Would be great if you can give me a hint.

Comment: Ok, I see, you have a really messed-up input. Use `\d+\.\s*\p{L}+\s*\d{4}` regex.

Answer (score 2):

I think this regex will be useful for you:

```
(\d{1,2}\s*\.\s*[^\d]+\d{4})
```

Comment: Thank you! Works nearly perfect, but catches also **"1. My christmas gift 2015"**. Is there a way to forbid whitespaces in between?

Comment: `(\d{1,2}\s*\.\s*\S+\s*\d{4})`